# Safely handling PDFs and other ebook formats on Linux

Tags: security, pdf, documents, ebooks, epub

I'm running Arch Linux and using Okular for opening PDF files and FBReader for other ebook formats (Epub, Mobi, etc.). Simply put, here's my question: Assuming some of those documents come from unreliable sources and contain malicious code what can I do to mitigate the risk of compromising the system and opening it for invasion (which can be a common occurrence in this country if you even smell like someone who holds opinions the government disapprove of)?

A few more specific questions:

Is just opening the referred files enough to put my setup at serious risk? The user I use for this is on the sudoers list, so, if compromised, it could be used for escalation.

Suppose I only open the files using a more limited user account, would that at least help?

Outside of setting up a virtual machine only for reading (which wouldn't be practical for a few reasons) or using another computer just for that (same thing), is there anything I can do?

Comment: clamav might be useful in this case!

Comment: [firejail](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/firejail)

Comment: You could use some form of 'mandatory access control' - eg SELinux, Apparmor. This would limit the impact the damage if you did open a dodgy file.

Answer (score 0):

You need antivirus. You can use [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/) which is an open source antivirus program for detecting trojans, viruses, malware & other malicious threats. This program is an open-source, free and works under these environments:

`Debian, RHEL/CentOS, Fedora, Mandriva, Gentoo, openSUSE, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, Solaris, Slackware, in addition to Windows, OpenVMS, OSX`.
You can find more information [here](https://www.clamav.net/documents/installing-clamav).

In the [manual](https://github.com/vrtadmin/clamav-faq/raw/master/manual/clamdoc.pdf), CalmAV can scan wide range of files including PDF formats.
For your system Arch Linux you can follow [these](https://pikedom.com/clam-anti-virus-on-arch-linux/) steps to install the program.

The second option is [Sophos](https://www.sophos.com/en-us.aspx), this program is not open-source and not free. More information can be reached in [here](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-antivirus-for-linux.aspx).